# Access SQL LEFT JOIN not returning results

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I have three tables: Comments, Users and CommentsHelpfulness.

Users can submit several comments, which are stored in the Comments table.

CommentsHelpfulness has three columns: UserID, CommentID and a "Helpful" Boolean. Every user can indicate for every comment if they find it useful, which will create an entry in the CommentsHelpfulness table.

I want a query that gives me all Comment IDs, with the name of the user that submitted it and shows whether the currently logged in user found it helpful, did not find it helpful or did not say anything about it. So the ID of a comment the current user did not express his opinion about should still be output, just without the helpful Boolean.

To me that sounds like it should be done like this using a left join:

`SELECT Comments.ID, Users.Nom, CommentsHelpfulness.Helpful
    FROM (Comments INNER JOIN Users
    ON Comments.UserID = Users.ID)
    LEFT JOIN CommentsHelpfulness
    ON (CommentsHelpfulness.CommentID = Comments.ID
    AND (CommentsHelpfulness.UserID = ?))`

Unfortunately this does not output Comment IDs without an entry in the CommentsHelpfulness table. Why does this not work? Is it because of Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the `inner join`, not the `left join`.

Try removing that table:

```
SELECT c.ID, ch.Helpful
FROM Comments as c LEFT JOIN
     CommentsHelpfulness as ch
     ON ch.CommentID = c.ID AND
        ch.UserID = ?
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to make the query as short as possible for my question and took some of the fields out I need. I actually need the Username from the Users table as well. I edited my question.

Comment: But you're right, if I take the INNER JOIN out it works. I just have to find a way now to also get the data I need from the Users table.

Comment: It turns out the problem is just the way I add the parameters, the query actually works fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.id, c.Nom, d.Helpful from (
select a.ID, b.Nom from Comments a left join Users b
on a.UserID = b.ID) c left join CommentsHelpfulness d
on d.CommentID = c.ID;
```